# stop auto unpersist of dataframe after writing to hive table

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, pyspark, persist

I want to persist a dataframe even after writing to hive table.

```
<change data capture code> 
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df.count() #count is 100
df.write.mode("append").insertInto("schema.table")
df.count() #count is 0 || because it's recalculating change data capture part
```

Here it seems that df is getting unpersisted after writing to hive.
Is this behavior expected if yes then how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can persist rdd after converting df to rdd.**

Storing schema so that we can convert back rdd to df

```
rdd_schema = df.schema
df_rdd = df.rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

df.count() #count is 100
df.write.mode("append").insertInto("schema.table")
```

Now df is gone so we can use persisted rdd to get back df

```
df_persisted = spark.createDataFrame(df_rdd, schema=rdd_schema)
df_persisted.count() #count is 100 || This will calculate from persisted rdd
```